# How do I convert (shred) arbitrary XML to a flat data structure?

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, sas

> *Not actually a duplicate of [Import arbitrary XML to SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10209445/import-arbitrary-xml-to-sql-server)*

My company has 20 GB of XML files that they want to do some data mining against. The analytics tool they will be using is SAS, which I have never used - someone else will be doing the actual mining. My job is to find a way to convert the XML files into a relatively flat data structure so they can be imported into SAS. The files have come from a half-dozen different sources over the course of six years. While they all nominally describe the same thing - the (very detailed) results of a credit inquiry - they don't follow a consistent format, even with files that come from the same source, because the version of the document has changed significantly over time. There are no XSL, XSD, or XSLT documents available.

It seems the answer would be "you want a document database", but apparently SAS needs either something flat, like a CSV or other wide-table structure, or something relational. My experience is primarily in SQL Server, but if there are solutions that target other platforms, we are definitely open to that. We've even looked into using Microsoft Excel, but it doesn't interpret the file correctly (it parses just fine, but it gives the columns nonsensical names).

I've entertained the idea of writing C# code to generate a SQL schema based on the XML data, and hoping that, at least within the scope of an individual source, the structures could be made consistent enough to fit all the files. I've looked into using [SQLXML Bulk Load](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171878(v=sql.110).aspx) to generate the tables, but this requires a SQL-annotated XSD schema, and [there doesn't appear to be any tool to generate this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4039085/xsd-schema-file-must-be-annotated-in-sqlxmlbulkloadlib-sqlxmlbulkload4class).

We've looked at using the [xml Data Type Methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190798.aspx) to get the data into a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE ResponseData
(
    CustomerID INT,
    NodePath VARCHAR(500),
    Position SMALLINT,
    Value VARCHAR(500)
)
```

but feel there must be a way to get more useful information separation than that.

There's plenty of information out there (including [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19304714/shred-data-into-table-by-using-xml) [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466826/importing-and-shredding-xml-into-sql-table) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29500860/xml-shredding-into-sql-server)) about how to convert a known XML document to SQL, but I need to know how to import an arbitrary XML document. "Import XML with an unknown structure" turned up a few suggested tools, but their output isn't that helpful.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I just want to say I'm sorry.

Comment: You could convert the XML to a list of key/value pairs where the key is the [the XPath to an XElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451950/get-the-xpath-to-an-xelement) and the value is the element value plus the attribute names & values.

Comment: SAS can read XML - but arbitrary data structures are annoying. If Excel can parse the file my experience is the XML mapper in SAS will as well.

Comment: Here's a link to how this could be done in SAS. You could write a macro to import all your files and then do whatever ETL you needed on the individual files to aggregate them together. https://communities.sas.com/message/218171#218171

Comment: Do you have just one XML structure, or many?  You say 'arbitrary', is this specifically there to mean you have many different structures?

Comment: Also - you might want to talk to the SAS developer.  It's possible they only need some portion of the data, and that might be obtainable either via straight-up text parsing (which SAS is quite good at) or by treating it like an HTML file (criminal, I know) and parsing it that way.

Comment: @Joe, at this point they want 100% of the data because they don't exactly know what's in it and they want to go through all of it. What I mean by arbitrary/many structures is that if you were to derive an XSD from each of the ~500,000 documents, you'd get dozens of distinct outputs.

Comment: If it were me I'd tell them to hire a SAS developer (not a statistician, but an actual data-step-programmer) and tell them to figure it out.  Silly to add the extra step.  SAS is as good or better at this kind of import itself as SQL Server.  (If it were me I'd actually be that developer of course, but if I were not me... >goes into infinite loop<

Comment: I work with SAS and credit inquiry results in XML format so I'm familiar with the pain you are experiencing.  Personally I think that if you were to try and convert it all to normalized tables, it would result in an overly complicated structure that's likely to be incorrectly joined to create bad data.  I really think that the analysts need to spend some initial investigative time understanding what is coming back in the CI, and then choosing which sections they feel are most important.  Honestly, most of it comes down to a handful of pieces of information anyway.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably obvious, but I think you're going to have to start by opening several files from different time periods and try to get a feel for how many "schemas" you're dealing with (in the XML sense).  Then you could write some code to systematically read files, trying to identify their "schema" and logging files that don't match any of your known types.  The goal is to figure out how many types of document you really have; after that, you can worry about how to get them into a database, one type at a time, hopefully settling on a single DB schema that can fully represent a document from any type.  I realize I haven't said much technical here, but I think what you have right now is a strategy problem, not a technical one.

Answer (score 2):

I figured I'd list these here as even if they don't help you, they may help someone else in future searching for a similar solution.

We use the below two macros in SAS to extract certain attributes, elements, values, etc. from XML credit inquiries.  I've provided examples which I'm hoping will help explain how they work.  I don't have time right now to go through it in detail, but wanted to provide something that you may find useful in the meantime.  If you provide these to the analysts, they should be able to run the code as-is, and working through the examples and parameters, extract some information for themselves to do preliminary investigations and maybe give you more concrete requirements.

The only condition for the below macros, is that the XML is no longer than 32767 chars, and that it's all in a single character observation on a single row in SAS (ie. not stored over multiple observations in SAS).

They shouldn't really need to understand how the macros work, they just need to understand how to call and use them.

```
/*****************************************************************************
**  PROGRAM: MACROS.PRXCOUNT.SAS
**
**  RETURNS THE NUMBER OF TIMES A SEGMENT IS FOUND IN AN XML FILE.
**  
**  PARAMETERS:
**  iElement      : The element to search through the blob for.
**  iXMLField     : The name of the field that contains the XML blob to parse.
**  iDelimiterType: (1 or 2). Defaults to 1.  1 USES <> AS DELIMS. 2 USES [].
**
******************************************************************************
**  HISTORY:
**  1.0 MODIFIED: 25-FEB-2011  BY:RP
**  - CREATED. 
**  1.1 MODIFIED: 14-MAR-2011  BY:RP
**  - MODIFIED TO ALLOW FOR OPTIONAL ATTRIBUTES ON THE ELEMENT BEING SEARCHED FOR.
*****************************************************************************/

%macro prxCount(iElement=, iXMLField=, iDelimiterType=1);

  %local delim_open delim_close;

  crLf = byte(10) || byte(13);
  &iXMLField = compress(&iXMLField,crLf,);

  %if &iDelimiterType eq 1 %then %do;
    %let delim_open  = <;
    %let delim_close = >;
  %end;
  %else %if &iDelimiterType eq 2 %then %do;
    %let delim_open  = \[;
    %let delim_close = \];
  %end;
  %else %if &iDelimiterType eq 3 %then %do;
    %let delim_open  = %nrbquote(&)lt%quote(%str(;)) ;
    %let delim_close = %nrbquote(&)gt%quote(%str(;)) ;
  %end;
  %else %do;
    %put ERR%str()ROR (prxCount.sas): You specified an incorrect option for the iDelimiterType parameter.;
  %end;

  prx_id = prxparse("/&delim_open&iElement(\s+.*?&delim_close|&delim_close){1}?(.*?)&delim_open\/&iElement&delim_close/i"); 

  prx_count = 0;
  prx_start = 1;
  prx_stop  = length(&iXMLField);
  call prxnext(prx_id, prx_start, prx_stop, &iXMLField, prx_pos, prx_length);
  do while (prx_pos > 0);
    prx_count = prx_count + 1;
    call prxposn(prx_id, 1, prx_pos, prx_length);
    call prxnext(prx_id, prx_start, prx_stop, &iXMLField, prx_pos, prx_length);
  end;

  drop crLf prx_:;

%mend;






/*****************************************************************************
**  PROGRAM: PRXEXTRACT.SAS
**
**  SEARCHES THROUGH AN XML (OR HTML) FILE FOR AN ELEMENT AND EXTRACTS THE 
**  VALUE BETWEEN AN ELEMENTS TAGS.
**  
**  PARAMETERS:
**  iElement      : The element to search through the blob for.
**  iField        : The fieldname to save the result to.
**  iType         : (N or C) for Numeric or Character.
**  iLength       : The length of the field to create.  
**  iXMLField     : The name of the field that contains the XML blob to parse.
**  iDelimiterType: (1 or 2). Defaults to 1.  1 USES <> AS DELIMS. 2 USES [].
**
******************************************************************************
**  HISTORY:
**  1.0 MODIFIED: 14-FEB-2011  BY:RP
**  - CREATED. 
**  1.1 MODIFIED: 16-FEB-2011  BY:RP
**  - ADDED OPTION TO CHANGE DELIMITERS FROM <> TO []
**  1.1 MODIFIED: 17-FEB-2011  BY:RP
**  - CORRECTED ERROR WHEN MATCH RETURNS A LENGTH OF ZERO
**  - CORRECTED MISSING AMPERSAND FROM IDELIMITERTYPE CHECK.
**  - ADDED ESCAPING QUOTES TO [] DELIMITER TYPE
**  - CORRECTED WARNING WHEN MATCH RETURNS MISSING NUMERIC FIELD
**  1.2 MODIFIED: 25-FEB-2011  BY:RP
**  - ADDED DELIMITER TYPES TO WORK WITH MASKED HTML CODES
**  1.3 MODIFIED: 11-MAR-2011  BY:RP
**  - MODIFIED TO ALLOW FOR OPTIONAL ATTRIBUTES ON THE ELEMENT BEING SEARCHED FOR.
**  1.4 MODIFIED: 14-MAR-2011  BY:RP
**  - CORRECTED TO REMOVE FALSE MATCHES FROM PRIOR VERSION. ADDED EXAMPLE.
**  1.5 MODIFIED: 10-APR-2012  BY:RP
**  - CORRECTED PROBLEM WITH ZERO LENGTH STRING MATCHES
**  1.6 MODIFIED: 22-MAY-2012  BY:RP
**  - ADDED ABILITY TO CAPTURE ATTRIBUTES
*****************************************************************************/

%macro prxExtract(iElement=, iField=, iType=, iLength=, iXMLField=, iDelimiterType=1, iSequence=1, iAttributesField=);

  %local delim_open delim_close;

  crLf = byte(10) || byte(13);
  &iXMLField = compress(&iXMLField,crLf,);

  %if &iDelimiterType eq 1 %then %do;
    %let delim_open  = <;
    %let delim_close = >;
  %end;
  %else %if &iDelimiterType eq 2 %then %do;
    %let delim_open  = \[;
    %let delim_close = \];
  %end;
  %else %if &iDelimiterType eq 3 %then %do;
    %let delim_open  = %nrbquote(&)lt%quote(%str(;)) ;
    %let delim_close = %nrbquote(&)gt%quote(%str(;)) ;
  %end;
  %else %do;
    %put ERR%str()ROR (prxExtract.sas): You specified an incorrect option for the iDelimiterType parameter.;
  %end;

  %if %sysfunc(index(&iField,[)) %then %do;
    /* DONT DO THIS IF ITS AN ARRAY */
  %end;
  %else %do;
    %if "%upcase(&iType)" eq "N" %then %do;
      attrib &iField length=&iLength format=best.;
    %end;
    %else %do;
      attrib &iField length=$&iLength format=$&iLength..;
    %end;
  %end;

  /*
  ** BREAKDOWN OF REGULAR EXPRESSION (EXAMPLE USES < AND > AS DELIMS AND ANI AS THE ELEMENT BEING LOOKED FOR:
  **
  ** &delim_open&iElement                            -->  FINDS <ANI
  ** (\s+.*?&delim_close|&delim_close){1}?           -->  FINDS THE SHORTEST SINGLE INSTANCE OF EITHER:
  **                                                      - ONE OR MORE SPACES FOLLOWED BY ANYTHING UNTIL A > CHARACTER
  **                                                      - OR JUST A > CHARACTER
  **                                                      THE ?: JUST TELLS IT NOT TO CAPTURE WHAT IT FOUND INBETWEEN THE ( AND )
  ** (.*?)                                           -->  FINDS WHAT WE ARE SEARCHING FOR AND CAPTURES IT INTO BUFFER 1.
  ** &delim_open                                     -->  FINDS <
  ** \/                                              -->  FINDS THE / CHARACTER. THE FIRST SLASH ESCAPES IT SO IT KNOWS ITS NOT A SPECIAL REGEX SLASH
  ** &iElement&delim_close                           -->  FINDS ANI>
  */
  prx_id = prxparse("/&delim_open&iElement((\s+.*?)&delim_close|&delim_close){1}?(.*?)&delim_open\/&iElement&delim_close/i"); 

  prx_start = 1;
  prx_stop = length(&iXMLField);
  prx_sequence = 0;
  call prxnext(prx_id, prx_start, prx_stop, &iXMLField, prx_pos, prx_length);
  do while (prx_pos > 0);
    prx_sequence = prx_sequence + 1;
    if prx_sequence = &iSequence then do;
      if prx_length > 0 then do;

        call prxposn(prx_id, 3, prx_pos, prx_length);
        %if "%upcase(&iType)" eq "N" %then %do;
          length prx_tmp_n $200;
          prx_tmp_n = substr(&iXMLField, prx_pos, prx_length);
          if cats(prx_tmp_n) ne "" then do;
            &iField = input(substr(&iXMLField, prx_pos, prx_length), ?best.);
          end;
        %end;
        %else %do;          
          if prx_length ne 0 then do;
            &iField = substr(&iXMLField, prx_pos, prx_length);
          end;
          else do;
            &iField = "";
          end;
        %end;

        **
        ** ALSO SAVE THE ATTRIBUTES TO A FIELD IF REQUESTED
        *;
        %if "%upcase(&iAttributesField)" ne "" %then %do;
          call prxposn(prx_id, 2, prx_pos, prx_length);
          if prx_length ne 0 then do;
            &iAttributesField = substr(&iXMLField, prx_pos, prx_length);
          end;
          else do;
            &iAttributesField = "";
          end;
        %end;

      end;
    end;
    call prxnext(prx_id, prx_start, prx_stop, &iXMLField, prx_pos, prx_length);
  end;

  drop crLf prx:;

%mend;
```

Example for single element:

```
data example;

  xml = "<test><ANI2Digits>00</ANI2Digits><XNI xniattrib=1>7606256091</XNI><ANI>number2</ANI><ANI x=hmm y=yay>number3</ANI></test>"; * NOTE THE XML MUST BE ALL ON ONE LINE;

  %prxExtract(iElement=xni, iField=my_xni, iType=c, iLength=15, iXMLField=xml, iSequence=1, iAttributesField=my_xni_attribs);

run;
```

Example for repeating elements:

```
data example;

  xml = "<test><ANI2Digits>00</ANI2Digits><ANI>7606256091</ANI><ANI>number2</ANI><ANI x=hmm y=yay>number3</ANI></test>"; * NOTE THE XML MUST BE ALL ON ONE LINE;

  %prxExtract(iElement=ani2digits, iField=ani2digits, iType=c, iLength=50, iXMLField=xml);

  length ani1-ani6 $15;
  length attr1-attr6 $100;
  array arrani [1:6] $ ani1-ani6;
  array arrattr [1:6] $ attr1-attr6;
  %prxCount  (iElement=ani, iXMLField=xml, iDelimiterType=1);
  do cnt=1 to prx_count;
    %prxExtract(iElement=ani, iField=arrani[cnt], iType=c, iLength=15, iXMLField=xml, iSequence=cnt, iAttributesField=arrattr[cnt]);
  end;

run;
```